# Font style and size not affected in mobile view for some time of period in windows universal platform app

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp

I am working on windows universal app. In that I'm managing three views:

1. Mobile View
2. Tabulate View
3. Desktop View

I am facing the issue regarding font size and style in mobile view.
Actually I'm using a visual state manager to manage all three views. But when I start my app in mobile view the font size is large for some time of period, means that visual state not manage the font size initially on app start.

Code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PageSizeStatesGroup"                                     CurrentStateChanged="OnCurrentStateChanged">
            <VisualState x:Name="MobileState">
                 <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                      <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="320"  />
                 </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                 <VisualState.Setters>            
                      <Setter Target="view_more.FontSize" Value="12"/>      
                 </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>            
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>      

       <HyperlinkButton Visibility="Visible"  Name="View_more" Content="View More" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FFF05929"  Click="View_more_Click" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="22" Margin="0,-38,15,0"  FontFamily="Utsaah" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Load More" ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" >
</Grid>
```

I used this code and manage the view through the visual manager. And also my background image doesn't display in mobile view.

Comment: Hi there! Please post the relevant code so that we can look for the problem. Also, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NahuelIanni:I added my code so please suggest me what's the problem.

Comment: @NahuelIanni:I edited the code in view_more line you can just check it .I added the Font-Family in that line.

Comment: It looks good from my POV. Did you try using a custom view just for the mobile device family? Just to check if it is being processed correctly or not.

Comment: You say "..for some time of period..", it means that after some time it gets smaller or it still stays large? It's just after some time or it's after some action (click, rotate screen...)?

Comment: @M.Pipal: after some time the font automatically small .but when we close the emulator and restart the app the font size looks larger.

Comment: May be the Windows mobile phone use a default font size and after initialization the font decrease  i don't get any idea about this issue so please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Could you share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue? The code you've posted is not complete and when I try with your code, it works well.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT: yes I know its work well but sometimes its not working I just want to know the reason actually the code is same which i attached there is nothing change in the code.

Comment: As I can't reproduce your problem, I can't tell your the reason why you have this issue. IMHO, your code is right, it should be able to work.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT: yes i got the problem ,The problem is that I am using a font family Utsaah and Raavi both for whole application which are not available in the list of the microsoft Font family. I am attaching the link so you can easily ubderstand.  "     https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/fonts"

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT:So when the user start the app if the font-family not available in the list so it will download that font but in my case auto download is not working i think so. So please tell me solution about this issue.

Comment: Seems you've created a new question about this issue. Let's discuss in the new question: [Font style is not affected in Mobile view in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197123/font-style-is-not-affected-in-mobile-view-in-uwp).

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT:hey I am just waiting so please provide a response.

Comment: @HardikKothari: I've add a comment in your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197123/font-style-is-not-affected-in-mobile-view-in-uwp). Please have a check.